# Where can I find FBAR forms for prior years?

Tags: united-states, taxes, fbar

I was recently informed that I needed to complete the [Report of Foreign Bank and Financial Accounts](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f90221.pdf) for the previous six years. I've been hunting on the IRS website for the last half hour and can only find the 2011 version.

Could anyone help me locate the versions for 2006-2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hasn't changed, to the best of my knowledge. You can use the same form for each of the years. Make sure to write the correct year on line 1.

Be very careful at what you're doing though. You can get hit with a lot of fines and penalties for late filing. Get a qualified tax professional (EA/CPA/Attorney) to help you with this, and get you into [OVDI](http://www.irs.gov/newsroom/article/0,,id=234900,00.html), if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I just had this confirmed to me by an IRS employee. I'm going to go ahead and use multiple copies of the 2011 form, changing the year on them.

Comment: Also, I appreciate your warning about penalties. I'm in a non-standard situation tax-wise (I've lived in Canada all my life and my income's always been below my exemptions for living abroad) so I don't anticipate problems, personally. But most other people reading this post should probably take note.

Comment: @dB' FBAR has no exemptions for living abroad. You're confusing with FATCA. If you had more than $10K in your accounts - you must have reported. The penalties are for failure to report, so it doesn't matter if you had any tax liability. Be careful with what you're doing, most cases of FBAR causing problems were like you: Americans living abroad.

Comment: Ok, noted. Thx.